# SpringBoot creating a framework starter library

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am creating a library using spring-boot (v2.1.6.RELEASE) as a starter project that will facilitate as base extension jar responsible for configuring and starting up some of the components based on client project properties file.

The issue I am facing is that if the client project's SpringBoot Application class contains the same package path as library everything works like charm! but when client project contains different package path and includes ComponentScan, it is not able to load or start components from the library.

**Did anyone encounter this issue? how to make client application to auto-configure some of the components from library jar?**

Note: I am following the library creation example from here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things that can go wrong here, without seeing relevant parts of actual code its hard to tell something concrete. Out of my head, here are a couple of points for consideration that can hopefully lead to the solution:

1. Since we use starters in our applications (and sometimes people use explicit component scanning in there spring applications) and this obviously works, probably the issue is with the starter module itself. Don't think that the fact that the component scan is used alone prevents the starter from being loaded ;)
2. Make sure the starter is a: regular library and not packaged as a spring boot application (read you don't use spring boot plugin) and have `<packaging>jar</packaging>` in your pom.xml or whatever you use to build.
3. Make sure you have: `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` file
   (case sensitive and everything)
4. Make sure that this `spring.factories` file indeed contains a valid reference on your configuration (java class annotated with @Configuration). If you use component scanning in the same package, it will find and load this configuration even without spring factories, in this case, its just kind of another portion of your code just packaged as a separate jar. So this looks especially "suspicious" to me.
5. Make sure that @Configuration doesn't have `@Conditional`-something - maybe this condition is not obeyed and the configuration doesn't start. For debugging purposes maybe you even should remove these `@Conditional` annotations just to ensure that the Configuration starts. You can also provide some logging inside the `@Configuration` class, like: "loading my cool library".